# Draw box around a grid of plots in R

Tags: r

I have arranged eight ggplots underneath each other in two columns with `plot_grid`. How can I draw a box around the entire grid?

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175766/draw-border-around-certain-rows-using-cowplot-and-ggplot2

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you can use the function `panel_border` as described in the following link:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cowplot/versions/1.0.0/topics/panel_border

Which adds an outer border to figures. I could not test that because you didn't added any piece of code that reproduce your result or a similar one.

**EDIT:**

as *Matt* said, the function `panel_border` is per plot, and not the entire plot image as desired. a solution with a dummy example is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = c('A', 'B'))+
theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=5))
```

Is to use `theme` combined with its attribute `panel.border` the results is:

[image]

As can be seen the border is on the entire plot and not per graph.

Comment: It is my understanding that `panel_border` adds a border around the plot panel but not around the entire graph as I will need.